software updates very slow 24.04
I have 24.04 and the updates are very slow. Let that be as it may, the problem is I leave the machine alone to finish. What happens? The screen times out and goes dark. That stops the update process.
When I come back it jumps back to some "safe" spot and starts from that point. Several times it was updating snaps, which again will time out. (I think my time out is 10 or 15 minutes.)
I think a work around is in order. When doing an update the system should refuse to blank the screen. Otherwise it keeps going back to "safe" places to continue.
On my end I guess I could change my machine to never time out. That is not good as I don't want it to eat up my battery if the laptop isn't on external power. A nicer solution would be the have the system not blank the screen if it is doing an update.
This wasn't a problem in the past.

I noticed that, in my case it was network settings, check your network.

What did you notice in network settings? I am going through WiFi where the laptop is fairly close to the router, so it should be fast. I also had System Monitor running and the traffic was quite low. Updating snaps for example is on my local machine (I suspect), so why is it slow? (It was only update snaps, but that caught my eye.)

I have dual band wifi, when I was connected to 5 ghz I had problems, if your wifi is dual band, try the other one.

I keep an eye open next time there are updates. Quite often I use System Monitor, and I noticed there was essentially no activity. Even the CPU wasn't working very hard. I wonder how much activity you would have seen? (YouTube works fine, so nothing major seems to be wrong.)

A question, is it only snap or do you have that also with apt?

This one came when the Software Updater poped up and suggested an update, so it took care of the snap as well. So far there are no new updates.

Something you may ty, do not think it applies to snap but it may. Go to Software  & Updatea on the first page you have Download from,  choose Other, on the opened window choose Select Best Server, it will choose the fastest possible server for you

Updates aren't terribly often, so I'll try next time it comes around. I keep wondering if this is a one off problem, or is it common? The nice thing is it DID finish, even after a long wait. I don't think there is anything special about the snap. It just seemed to get stuck there. Why??? My idea was to suggest at least to turn off the screen blanking, because that seems to pause the process, which just wastes my time.

Also it is possible that at that time your routing was through a very slow or congested network, nothing can be done about that but if it happens all the time you should look at it or talk to your ISP.
